# beforeNavigate not firing every time

Tags: safari-extension

I built an extension for Safari, that blocks certain pages from loading. For the goal I listen to the beforeNavigate event and evaluate if the request should be blocked.

However I noticed that it will be working when following links, but only most of the times if you manually input the URL in the address bar (not firing at all, tracked with console.log). I didn't find anything in the documentation mentioning that beforeNavigate is fired in only certain occasions. Do you know if there are any specifics do this?

Also, working with beforeLoad in a start script actually didn't work as expected and wasn't blocking the whole site from loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the exact same thing. I've confirmed with this fellow's [debugging script](https://github.com/freewizard/SafariTabMix/blob/master/TabMix.safariextension/debug.js) that `beforeSearch` only fires when doing a search. In those circumstances, `beforeNavigate` subsequently fires as well.

Also, `beforeNavigate` doesn't seem to work everywhere. Try listening for it on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `beforeSearch` event that gets called instead when typing a search term into the address bar instead of a URL.

There is also a `navigate` event, but that might get called at too late for your purposes.

Comment: Does that mean that beforeSearch is triggered and even if it's a domain name beforeNavigate is not?